# Gedcom file with Person/Individual containing multiple Places/Residences

Tags: gedcom

I want to create a `Gedcom` file which contains information about the places where the person lived in the course of his life.
But in `GEDCOM 5.5.1` as I understood it the `ADDR` & `RESI` tags contain only one  address but there is no tag for multiple places.

I have solved it so far by using multiple `RESI` tags:

```
0 @I1@ INDI
1 NAME John Smith
1 SEX M
1 BIRT
2 DATE 15 APR 1963
2 PLAC Berlin
1 RESI
2 DATE 1999
2 PLAC London
1 RESI
2 DATE 2000
2 PLAC Vienna
1 RESI
2 DATE 2000
2 PLAC Washington
1 FAMS @F!@
```

My question is, if this is the best approach or if their is a better one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiple **RESI** tags are the proper way to do this. If you think about it each is an 'event' in that persons life. They live in 'place 1' when they are born and then in 'place 2' when they leave home and marry etc etc. Don't forget that you can use **PLAC** and **ADDR** in the same **RESI** record.

This is an example from one of my Gedcoms

`1 RESI
2 DATE ABT 1956
2 PLAC Newcastle under Lyme, Staffordshire
2 ADDR 1 The Crossway, Newcastle under Lyme, Staffordshire
1 RESI
2 DATE ABT 1963
2 PLAC Throop, Dorset
2 ADDR The Village Stores
1 RESI
2 DATE ABT 1965
2 PLAC Northbourne, Bournemouth, Dorset
2 ADDR Greenacres Close`